# The definition of two-sided uniformity

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, uniform-spaces

In the field of uniform spaces, what does it mean to be a two-sided uniformity? Could not find a clear definition of this online.

Comment: This is a thing in topological groups I believe?

Comment: Yes you are right, I added this as well

Comment: With regard to the entourage definition of uniformioty, it might be another name for a symmetric system of entourages? More context might be helpful

Comment: I think it means that both all right multiplications and left multiplications are uniformly continuous. Normally, only one of them is, in the standard uniformities on a topological group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Definition $2.2$ in [**1**]:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological group. The supremum $\mathfrak{L}\vee
>  \mathfrak{R}$ of the left and right uniformities  $\mathfrak{L}$ and
>    $\mathfrak{R}$ of $(X,\tau)$ will be called the **upper uniformity** or,
>    more traditionally, the **two-sided uniformity** of $(X,\tau)$.

The basis for this uniformity is formed by the sets
$$\{(x,y)\in X\times X: y\in xU\cap Ux\}$$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of the identity.

[**1**] W. Roelcke, S. Dierolf, *Uniform Structures on Topological Groups and their Quotients* (1981).